# How To Ensure Reference Data Is Loaded In Vue?

Tags: vuejs2

I have webpack setup to bundle all of the source.  I have a Vue object that is the page and multiple Vue components of my own creation.  This works great!

I am now getting reference data from the database to fill in certain default options for some of these components.  In my pages `Mounted` or `Created` events (there is no difference for my question) I am calling a method that will check to see if the data exists in `localStorage` and if not, it will extract the data from the database.

Once Extracted, I have it in `localStorage` so it is not an issue.  However, the first time I need to gather the data (or when I need to refresh it because I have another trigger that lets me know when it has changed) the page and components have rendered (with errors because of lack of data) before the data comes back.  The fetch method is in a promise, but `mounted` events don't seem to care if a promise exists within in before it continues to the next component.

So what is the best practice for loading/refreshing reference data in Vue?  I am currently not using VueX because this is not a SPA.  Sure, it is a single page that is doing things (there are many single pages that do their own thing in this site) but I have no need to make it a full SPA here.  But If VueX and its `store` will give me some sort of guarantee that it will occur first or page/components will run AFTER VueX things, I will learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing so:

```
<component v-if="page.isDataLoaded">...</component>
```

in your Vue-component:

```
data() {
   return {
      page: {
         isDataLoaded: false,
      }
   }
},
mounted() {
   this.fetchPageData().then(() => this.page.isDataLoaded = true);
}
```

You can use `v-if` and `v-else` to show, for example page loader element like so:

```
<PageLoader v-if="!page.isDataLoaded"></PageLoader>
<component v-else>...</component>
```

Comment: I have an `init` property on the page, I could implement this rather easily.  Thank you!