# How To Ensure Async Components Are All Loaded And Ready Before ViewModel Mounted Event Triggers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vanilla `Vue` meaning no `Vuex` and no `Vue-router`.  `Webpack` does what it does for me.

I have a page (dumbing it down for clarity here) that has many controls on it.  Some need to load data via `async await` calls.  Others do not.  My issue is with the `async` one of course.

Here is the basic page:

```
<p>My Page</p>
<medications ref="Medications"></medications>
```

Here is the code for it:

```
export default {
  extends: BaseTest,
  data: {
    ...
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Mounted Page - Total Meds:', this.$refs.Medications.Meds.length);
  }
};
```

Here is the `async` component that is causing me issues `Medications.vue`:

```
<template id="medications-template">
  <div class="medications">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    extends: BaseComponent,
    name: 'medications',
    props: {
      Meds: []
    },
    data() { return { ... } },
    async created() {
      console.log('Creating a Medications control');
      let Meds = await getClinicalList('...', '...');
      console.log('Done creating a Medications control - Total Meds:', this.Meds.length);
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('Mounted a Medications control - Total Meds:', this.Meds.length);
    }
  };
</script>
```

When I run the page, the `console.log` messages are as follows:

- Creating a Medications control
- Mounted a Medications control - Total Meds: 0
- Mounted Page - Total Meds: 0
- Done creating a Medications control - Total Meds: 59

I assumed that any `async` components would `finish` loading prior to the outer view model/page does it `mounted` event.

Is there a way to ensure that all components are *done* before the actual page finishes?

Comment: Without using extra libraries, simplest approach might be to emit an event from the child component when its data is available and have the parent listen for the event and set a flag. Use a `v-show` on the parent to hide it until the flag is set.

Comment: I wound up going with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238189/373438)